# Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile() The project 'android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am stucked at this problem since 2-3 hours. I tried many solution from similar question but none is working. The gradle build was working fine but after changing min sdk level from 23 to 17 android studio started giving me this error.

Error:(32, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'Possible causes:

The project 'android' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project

The project 'android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Below are my gradle files:

build.gradle(project:android)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.transporttracker"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        resValue "string", "build_transport_id", (project.findProperty("build_transport_id") ?: "")
        resValue "string", "build_email", (project.findProperty("build_email") ?: "")
        resValue "string", "build_password", (project.findProperty("build_password") ?: "")
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

ext {
    support = '23.2.0'
    playServices = '10.2.4'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support" compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support" compile "com.android.support:design:$support" compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$playServices" compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$playServices" compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$playServices" compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$playServices" compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$playServices" compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$playServices" compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$playServices" compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try changing `"` to `'` in `dependencies`. Also I don't think you need `classpath` in dependencies remove that also.Also break compile statements into single lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is inside the dependencies closure: You can't write multiple compile statements in one line. Just write each compile statement in a separate line, than it will work.

I think it's a bug with auto-formatting when you use variables for the dependency versions and therefore wrap the dependencies in double quotes instead of single quotes.